# Smart-mode-line: Different colors for active and non active windows

Tags: smart-mode-line

Windows 10, Emacs 25.1

Here my mode line with 3 windows.

[image]

As you can see the mode line for active window (**text.html)** has more lighter color. And two another non active windows has more darker color for mode line.

Now, I want to try package **smart-mode-line:** https://github.com/Malabarba/smart-mode-line

Is a possible to have different colors mode-lines for active and non active windows?
I want to set my custom colors for active and non active mode-lines.

Comment: Those mode-line colors are controlled by faces `mode-line` and `mode-line-inactive`. If `smart-mode-line` overrides these faces, i.e., if it does not respect your customization of them, then consider filing a bug report / enhancement request with the `smart-mode-line` maintainer. If it does respect your customizations then just customize those faces, using`M-x customize-face`.

Comment: It looks like `smart-mode-line` wants you to use its own function to customize mode-line faces: `sml/customize-faces`.

Comment: `mode-line` and `mode-line-inactive` - this what I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Those mode-line colors are normally controlled by faces `mode-line` and `mode-line-inactive`.

It looks like `smart-mode-line` might want you to use its own function to customize mode-line faces: `sml/customize-faces`.  It may not respect / make use of the standard faces `mode-line` and `mode-line-inactive`.

The code of `smart-mode-line.el` has this comment:

```
;;  5. **Very easy to configure**:
;;     All colors and variables are customizable. You can change the
;;     whole theme with `sml/apply-theme', or just customize anything
;;     manually with `sml/customize' and `sml/customize-faces'. There are
;;     *DOZENS* of variables to customize your mode-line, just pop over
;;     there and have a look!
```

So try `M-x sml/customize-faces`.

And the doc string for Customize group `smart-mode-line-faces` says this:

> Note that, by default, `smart-mode-line` **overrides** your theme's
>   settings for the background and foreground color of the modeline
>   face. We need to override, otherwise some elements become
>   unreadable on lighter themes. If you'd rather configure these
>   unreadable colors yourself and keep your theme's settings, just
>   **set `sml/override-theme` to `nil`**.

So try setting `sml/override-theme` to `nil`, as another alternative.